# reading from xml and json using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, json

i'm trying to read data from xml and json files those files are on the same folder as the html they called show.xml and followers.json 
then post the data inside existing div tags by sing their ids
first function want it to works when the doc is read and the other when clicked
it makes no out put it print the html only

this is my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Shaden
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content_area" >
            <div class="profile_imge">

            </div>
            <div id="name">

            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="bio">

            </div>
            <p id="click_here">Click here to view my twitter followers</p>
            <div id="followers">

            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        <style>
            @font-face {
    font-family: my_font;
    src: url('channel.ttf');
}
            .profile_imge img {
               -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #888;
               -moz-border-radius: 15px;
               -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #888;
               -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
               shadow: 5px 5px 7px #888;
               border-radius:15px;
               border: solid;
               border-color: #DCDCDC;
            }
            #name{
                font-family: my_font; src: url('channel.ttf');
                font-size: x-large;
            }
            #followers img{
                -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
                border-radius:15px;
            }
            #content_area {
                width: 700px ;
                margin-left: auto ;
                margin-right: auto ;
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                   url: "show.xml",
                   dataType: "xml",
                   success: function(xml) {
                              var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                              var bio = $(this).find('description').text();
                              var imge_url = $(this).find('profile_image_url').text();
                              $(".profile_imge div").append(imge_url);
                              $("#name").append(name);
                              $("#bio").append(bio);
                       }
            }) ;
            });
                $("#click_here").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                   url: "followers.json",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(json) {
                              json.id.each(function(){
                             var imge_url = $(this).find('profile_image_url').text();
                              $("#followers").append(imge_url);}) ;
                       }
            }) ;
                });
        </script>

    </html>
```

this is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <id>122890543</id>
  <name>Shaden Al Omran</name>
  <screen_name>shadoon91</screen_name>
  <location>KSA , Riyadh</location>
  <profile_image_url>http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2626407130/image_normal.jpg</profile_image_url>
  <profile_image_url_https>https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2626407130/image_normal.jpg</profile_image_url_https>
  <url>http://shadoon91.blog.com</url>
  <description>Saudi girl,IT student in KSU,Microsoft Student Partner,programing and architecture r the most 2 interesting things4 me =]..i write everything comes 2 my mind :)</description>
  <protected>false</protected>
  <followers_count>76</followers_count>
  <profile_background_color>C0DEED</profile_background_color>
  <profile_text_color>333333</profile_text_color>
  <profile_link_color>0084B4</profile_link_color>
  <profile_sidebar_fill_color>DDEEF6</profile_sidebar_fill_color>
  <profile_sidebar_border_color>C0DEED</profile_sidebar_border_color>
  <friends_count>60</friends_count>
  <created_at>Sun Mar 14 07:28:05 +0000 2010</created_at>
  <favourites_count>1</favourites_count>
  <utc_offset>10800</utc_offset>
  <time_zone>Riyadh</time_zone>
  <profile_background_image_url>http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png</profile_background_image_url>
  <profile_background_image_url_https>https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png</profile_background_image_url_https>
  <profile_background_tile>false</profile_background_tile>
  <profile_use_background_image>true</profile_use_background_image>
  <geo_enabled>true</geo_enabled>
  <verified>false</verified>
  <statuses_count>6941</statuses_count>
  <lang>en</lang>
  <contributors_enabled>false</contributors_enabled>
  <is_translator>false</is_translator>
  <listed_count>1</listed_count>
  <default_profile>true</default_profile>
  <default_profile_image>false</default_profile_image>
  <following></following>
  <follow_request_sent></follow_request_sent>
  <notifications></notifications>
</user>
```

this is the json (it's too large)
http://430201246.it341.com/MS2/fallowers.json

Comment: There are 100 kinds of wrong with this one

Comment: @raam86 could u plz tell me what are they ??

Comment: please post your json and your xml....:)

Comment: @viyancs they r from the twitter .. i'm sure there is no errores show.xml is my account info and the json is my followers info

Comment: yes you right , but with data json i can see what is incorect on your code by matching json data or xml data with your code, i believe twitter is not error...:)

Comment: @viyancs sure i'll post them now ^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the JSON is that you cannot use methods like "find" against json. You would need to change it to something like:

```
$("#click_here").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                   url: "followers.json",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(json) {
                             json.id.each(function() { 
                               var imge_url = $(this).find('profile_image_url').text();
                               $("followers").append(imge_url);})
                             });
                       }
            }).
```

For the XML, you are so close its painful!

```
$.ajax({
                   url: "show.xml",
                   dataType: "xml",
                   success: function(xml) {
                              var name = $(xml).find('name').text();
                              var bio = $(xml).find('description').text();
                              var imge_url = $(xml).find('profile_image_url').text();
                              $("profile_imge").append(imge_url);
                              $("name").append(name);
                              $("bio").append(bio);
                       }
```